# How to dynamically add/render Kendo UI controls in kendo ui grid - Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can we create kendo ui controls dynamically? I have Angular Kendo UI grid, one column is name of control and depending on that I want to render Kendo control in next column.

I can't use ngSwitch or ngIf as I don't want to already keep html and just hide unhide. I want to render elements runtime.

| Column 1 | Column 2---------------- |
| --- | --- |
| Dropdown | kendo-combobox contorl |
| Date | kendo-datepicker |

As per above, my first row's column name should render combo box and second row should show date picker and so on.